# Difference between .filter() and .where() in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've seen a few variations of running a query with SQLAlchemy. For example, here is one version:

```
posts = db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.owner_id==user.id).all()
```

What would be the difference between using the above or using `.where`? Why are there two variations here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.where), there is no difference.

> method `sqlalchemy.orm.Query.where(*criterion)`
>
> A synonym for `Query.filter()`.

It was added in version 1.4 by [this commit](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/5de0f1cf50cc0170d8ea61304e7b887259ab577b). According to the commit message the reason to add it was to *Convert remaining ORM APIs to support 2.0 style*.

You can read more about "2.0 style" [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/glossary.html#term-2.0-style).